# How to give series name as label on yaxis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

how to give y axis label as series name
ex :- if i have series,

```
series: [{
        name:'Art & Architecture',
        data: [{x:0,y:46.9,mname:"dhan"},{x:1,y:57.4}]
    },{
        name:'Business',
        data: [{x:0,y:44},{x:1,y:55.8}]
    },{
         name:'Literature',
         data: [{x:0,y:43.5},{x:1,y:52.2}]
     },{
         name:'Books - Miscellaneous',
         data: [{x:0,y:40.7},{x:1,y:45.5}]
     },{
         name:'Cameras',
         data: [{x:0,y:39},{x:1,y:43.5}]
     },{
         name:'Computers',
         data: [{x:0,y:37.5},{x:1,y:41.9}]
     },{
         name:'Audio Equipment',
         data: [{x:0,y:35.2},{x:1,y:39.2}]
     }]
```

i want to give this names on y axis.

Comment: can you write an example of output expected

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.